# Escape sequence not working as desired

Tags: java

I have to read a file and then write something to some output file.
In both input and output files, I used pipeline delimiter :-

```
private static final String COLUMNDELIMITER = "\\|";
```

I can read the input file perfectly but for the output file, the lines are coming as below:

```
abc\|123\|kk
```

But I want it to be:

```
abc|123|kk
```

Why the same delimiter behaving differently for read and write?

When I am reading a line, I am using:

```
String[] elements = record.split(COLUMNDELIMITER); //works perfect
```

And while writing I am using:

```
String lineToWrite = String1 + COLUMNDELIMITER + String2 + COLUMNDELIMITER + String3 //Does not work rightly
```

Comment: You should post the code you're running for reading and writing. My first guess is that your read code is expecting a regex instead of a delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.split` takes a regular expression, and a pipe (`|`) has special meaning, so it needs to be escaped. This is done using a backslash (`\`), which needs to be escaped in Java strings, so you need to use double-backslash (\) in the string literal. However, when concatenating, you just need `|`, not `\|`.

So, instead use:

```
private static final String COLUMNDELIMITER = "|";
```

And when splitting, quote it using [`java.util.regex.Pattern#quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-):

```
String[] elements = record.split(Pattern.quote(COLUMNDELIMITER));
```

Your concatenation will then just work.